# How many characters does the SMILES notation uses?

Tags: notation

I am not a chemist, in fact, I come from a computer science background, however, I am working on a project that involves using machine learning for SMILES generation.
My question is, how many characters are used in the SMILES notation and what are they?
I looked it up with no success!

Comment: For more than two decades, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplified_molecular-input_line-entry_system) dedicates an entry about SMILES, including references to *primary* references (including Weiniger's seminal paper in 1988).  There are multiple variations of SMILES (e.g., unique, canonical, inchified; see e.g. [here](https://open-babel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/FileFormats/SMILES_format.html)), and other string notations (like the more recent InChI), too.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that for generative ML applications, [DeepSMILES](https://github.com/baoilleach/deepsmiles) or [SELFIES](https://github.com/aspuru-guzik-group/selfies) are consistently better.

Comment: Thank you for this information. However, I still cannot find any source listing all the characters used in the SMILES notation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A brief glance on the documentation by [Daylight](https://daylight.com/dayhtml/doc/theory/theory.smiles.html) suggests for the typical organic molecules:

- you need all characters to represent a chemical element by the symbol in the periodic table of elements.  Likely, this condenses to `[A-Za-z]`.  Note, though, while upper case `C` and lower case `c` both refers to carbon, the second one is part of an aromatic system; e.g. `C1CCCCC1` about cyclohexane, but `c1ccccn1` about pyridine.
- coverage of all `[0-9]`, because you may refer explicitly to isotopes if necessary, e.g. `[13C]` about $\ce{^{13}C}$.
- `=` and `#` marks double and triple bonds.  Single bonds *may* be noted by `-` (but often are implicit); on occasion you meet `:`.
- stereochemical configuartion may be indicated by `/` and `\` around double bonds (used pairwise) about (*cis*/*trans*) relationships; or more general (*E*/*Z*).  For sterogenic centres (mainly carbon `C`, but not limited to this [e.g., [sulfoxides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulfoxide)]) you need the individual `@` or `@@` to indicate them as either (*S*), or (*R*), respectively.  Depending on the intended use, these four indicators may be absent or partially missing.
- Pairwise, parentheses `(` / `)` and square brackets `[` / `]` are used.  E.g., `C(O)C` is about ethanol, while `COC` describes dimethyl ether.  With the brackets you mark start and end of the elements with more than a single letter; e.g., `[Sn]` about tin, while `S` were about sulfur and `n` were about an aromatic nitrogen.

  Brackets are in place to mark charges, like `[Fe+2]` or `[Fe++]` (functional equivalent) about $\ce{Fe^{2+}}$, or `[OH-]` about $\ce{OH^-}$.
- there are complex ring closures (e.g., in [buckyball fullerenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckminsterfullerene)) described with the `%` sign.  (Credit to `@Geoff Hutchison` to pointing to this detail.)
- You need the full stop / period `.` to join e.g., multiple molecules or ions into one SMILES string, like for sodium acetate: `[Na+].[O-]C(=O)C`

If you stop here, the set of `A-Za-z0-9=#:+-[]()/\@.%` is a key space of 76 characters.

The lower part of the document documents some keywords reserved to describe the spatial constitution of complexes of transition metal complexes, and the use of `>` to encode reactions.

Noel M O'Boyle wrote a paper about the methods to identify a canonical SMILES representation of (organic) structures which provides insight here, too.

*Towards a Universal SMILES representation - A standard method to generate canonical SMILES based on the InChI* in *J. Cheminf.* **2012**; [doi 10.1186/1758-2946-4-22](https://jcheminf.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1758-2946-4-22).

Comment: Great summary. You forgot % for extended ring closure, e.g. `C2%13%24` because some systems need more than just one digit for ring closures (e.g., fullerenes, other complex ring systems)

Comment: @GeoffHutchison Thank you for pointing the `%`.  So far, I didn't use SMILES about fullerenes and it was a new for me.