# Why do two programs assign different SMILES to one amino acid sequence?

Tags: cheminformatics, amino-acids

I have an amino acids string "MKGK" and I would like to convert it into [SMILES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplified_molecular-input_line-entry_system) format.

I tried two approaches.

First with [PepSMI](https://www.novoprolabs.com/tools/convert-peptide-to-smiles-string) which gives me:

```
N[C@@]([H])(CCSC)C(=O)N[C@@]([H])(CCCCN)C(=O)NCC(=O)N[C@@]([H])(CCCCN)C(=O)O
```

Second, using ChemAxon Marvin's [**molconvert**](https://docs.chemaxon.com/display/docs/molconvert.md) command

```
/Applications/MarvinSuite/bin/molconvert --peptide MKGK smiles
```

I get:

```
[H]N[C@@H](CCSC)C(=O)N[C@@H](CCCCN)C(=O)NCC(=O)N[C@@H](CCCCN)C(O)=O
```

Both of them give different result. Are they chemically the same?
If not, which result should I trust?

Finally is the conversion from amino-acid to SMILES is a lossless process?
Is there anything we should be careful about?

Answer (score 4):

TL,DR:  Despite differences on the string level, they all may be correct.

Very likely, the string `MKGK` you state is the compact representation of the primary structure of a structure (as in *sequence of amino acids*) by the [FASTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format) format.  For this purpose, FASTA is a more efficient string notation than SMILES.  Note, their scope is complementary to each other; FASTA has large (bio)molecules in mind (proteins, RNA/DNA), SMILES' focus in comparison are smaller molecules, though there is some overlap where both may be practical.  If choosing, you equally have to consider ease of storage, processing, already existing data and programs in the field you want to use when choosing one, or the other (e.g., [BioPerl](https://bioperl.org/), [BioPython](https://biopython.org/)).

FASTA and SMILES are both a simplified description of a structure.  Say, a tripeptide is described initially in a `.mol2` file.  Then, the description in a SMILES string will remove specific atomic coordinates in a description *like* «atoms $\ce{A1}$, $\ce{A2}$, $\ce{A3}$, $\ce{A4}$ are all around atom $\ce{A5}$ to form a (*R*) configurated stereogenic center» and only states that these form a (*R*) configuration. In addition, a *typical* SMILES string will remove all hydrogen atoms *except* those around a stereogenic centre. (You may retain these as explicit ones, though).  FASTA's description of amino acids in sequence equally is loosing *some* information, too.

What do you want to do once you have the SMILES string in hand?  At present, your question does not state this clearly enough.

The potential obstacle using SMILES is that it is one name *of multiple* definitions.  Often, programs do not explicitly state if the output is e.g., canonical, universal, or inchified to mention some of the options.  Other programs let you choose, e.g., [OpenBabel](https://open-babel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/FileFormats/SMILES_format.html).  Thus, once you pass a certain threshold of structural complexity of a molecular structure, the very same molecule may be described with multiple SMILES strings -- each of them may be a correct description *as such*, yet the at the level of the SMILES string, they differ. See, for example, O'Boyle's paper mentioned in [this recent answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/158969/how-many-characters-does-the-smiles-notation-uses/159017#159017) to resolve this potential confusion.  So it is up to you to check what form of SMILES the version of your program used provides and if this understood (input and output) by any other program you use while processing these strings.  (And turn off the autocorrect in the spread sheets, if you use them; it is an avoidable pitfall (see e.g., [Nature](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-021-02211-4)).

What do you want to do with the SMILES strings, once in hand?  Do you want to use them (eventually) to create atomic coordinates?  These won't be the originally recorded ones.  Do you want to engage in protein folding (possibly assisted by machine learning like AlphaFold [then see e.g., this potentially interesting thread [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/jmol/mailman/message/37372238/) about the now open submission of candidates])?  For small molecules [InChI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InChI) is a more recent string standardized notation, and its hashed form InChIKey provides a computationally affordable approach to check them for structure identity, e.g., in a database.

References implicitly mentioned:

Noel M O'Boyle *Towards a Universal SMILES representation - A standard method to generate canonical SMILES based on the InChI* in *J. Cheminf.* **2012**; [doi 10.1186/1758-2946-4-22](https://jcheminf.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1758-2946-4-22)

Dyani Lewis *Autocorrect errors in Excel still creating genomics headache* in *Nature*, 13th August 2021; [doi 10.1038/d41586-021-02211-4](https://doi.org/10.1038/d41586-021-02211-4)

Comment: Thank you so much for your clear and elaborate answer.
I'm using SMILES to extract features (e.g. number of amines, benzene, etc) and do machine learning predictions. 
Another usage of that SMILES is to do docking on a receptor using Vina Autodock (for example).
I need it because the peptide I have is so short (4 amino acids). It's hard to create a reasonable PDB structure using Alphafold etc. 
Do you think my intention and approach make sense?
Your expert advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Four amino acids per molecule, these still may be processed to generate *a* conformer (e.g., [OpenBabel](https://open-babel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/3DStructureGen/SingleConformer.html)) or multiple ones (e.g. [obabel](https://open-babel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/3DStructureGen/multipleconformers.html)) or to count fragments (e.g., [RDKit](https://www.rdkit.org/docs/Cookbook.html#highlight-a-substructure-in-a-molecule)). If you prefer a more GUI centered approach for e.g., a substructure count, [DataWarrior](https://openmolecules.org/help/chemistry.html#ChemicalStructures) offers this as well.

Comment: Contrasting to OpenBabel and RDKit, DataWarrior permits to initialize the tested conformations on data inferred from the [COD](http://www.crystallography.net/cod/), or -- like the other two -- from a force field.  Then it may be worth to convert FASTA (or SMILES) into `.sdf` (which OpenBabel offers on the fly, too) with atomic coordinates at least as an intermediate format.  However, I do not know, if `.mol2` or `.sdf` (the later may contain multiple `.mol2`) is an input format Vina Autodock accepts .or. if a conversion of `.sdf` into `.pdb` by, e.g. OpenBabel suits your needs.

Comment: thanks so much again. May I know what is a *conformer*. What's the command line for OpenBabel to generate that. Also for RDKIt how can we know which substructure to extract? Is there a way to extract all?

Comment: @scamander Since this requires multiple lines, it is better to continue this in the chemistry.se chatroom [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59458101#59458101).

Answer (score 2):

My answer may be too late, but there is very simple way to answer question initiating this topic.

SMILES representations should be converted into InChIKey. If they present the same molecule, they should result in the same InChIKey.

In contrast to SMILES, InChIkey for the same molecule is always the same. It is easy to be compared manually due to fact, that it contains only 27 characters.

I have translated above SMILES strings into InChIKey using Marvin JS molecule editor.
Both of them have given InChIKey=FGIPJUHCFCYWLW-KKUMJFAQSA-N.

For further reading:
Annotation of Peptide Structures Using SMILES and Other Chemical Codes–Practical Solutions. Minkiewicz p. et al., Molecules 2017, 22(12), 2075;
https://doi.org/10.3390/molecules22122075

Comment: You wouldn't actually need InChIKey, the standard InChI would have sufficed. So would have cononicalising the SMILES. Anyway, still a valid point.